# Is it possible to enable an extension programmatically in PHP?

Tags: php

We can enable php_zip by uncomment it in php.ini as follows:

```
;extension=php_zip.dll
```

How to do it programmably?

I'm using PHP5.3

Answer (score 6):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.dl.php

> dl — Loads a PHP extension at runtime

Why do you want to do it **pragmatically** though?

Comment: Yeah, load it via the php.ini