# php, mysqli and no access to ini file

Tags: php, mysqli

Is it possible to use the new mysqli functions if i don't have access to the php.ini file?

I'm on a hosted site that doesn't allow me access to the php.ini file and according to php documentation i need to add entries to the ini file to enable the mysqli functions. Is there a way around that?

In cpanel, I can see I have an php directory with associated sub directories which look mostly empty. I also have acess to a PHP PEAR Installer with some text saying that the admin has enabled autoload of PHP extensions but none of the PEAR packages says anything about mysqli apart from DB2 Driver mysqli

Comment: I hope you can't :) else this is a security bug at your provider.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to enable an extension programmatically in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2392845/is-it-possible-to-enable-an-extension-programmatically-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

In a default installation, and with most shared hosters, mysqli is already part of the deal.

You could check if its installed by issuing a phpinfo() and see if it is there.

With the default settings you are ok to go.

[image]